# jquery how to use..... addClass().find().text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the result I want:

```
<div id="error" class="alert warning"><span  class="icon"></span>text here</div>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#error').addClass('alert error').find('span').addClass('icon').text('text here');`
```

which results in this:

```
<div id="error" class="alert warning"><span class="icon">text here</span></div>
```

I also tried this:

```
$('#error').addClass('alert warning').text('text here').find('span').addClass('icon');
```

which results in this:

```
<div id="error-arch" class="alert warning">text here</div>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: And what do you start with?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `.text()` on the `div`, which replaces all of the `div`'s contents, us `append`:

```
$('#error')
    .addClass('alert warning').append('text here')
    .find('span').addClass('icon');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2ULf/

---

If you already have text in there, and you only want to replace it, you'll have to first find the text node:

```
$('#error').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).last()[0].nodeValue = 'New Text';
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2ULf/1/

Comment: yes, it works with .append('text here'), but it always dublicate text here text here text here

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#error')
    .addClass('error warning')
    .find('span')
    .addClass('icon')
    .after(
        function () {
            return document.createTextNode('text here');
        });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rbvey/).

Although I seem to have added the wrong class-names in the `addClass()`, but the theory's exactly the same, regardless, but obviously amend the class-names to those you want to add. And, in the linked-Fiddle, I had to guess at the starting HTML based on what you were adding/doing in your jQuery methods.